# How to add Marker with text not hover text using python gmplot

Tags: python, gmplot

I want to add a text to a specific point that text showing always on the map, not hover text. I added text to marker but that text not showing always if touch then shows but this not that I want. Please help me to find out the solution.

```
gmap.coloricon = "http://www.googlemapsmarkers.com/v1/%s/"
gmap.marker(latitude_list[-1], longitude_list[-1], '#FF0000',title ="FYO Car")
```

I want the title always showing in the map not hover text.